# How to shift line that I drew with HTML5 Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas

If you want to try out the code:
https://jsfiddle.net/csCoder/eLxfrn10/

I am trying to create a graph using javascript where I will be able to show y = mx + b equations. I have a few methods that would create the x and y axis and I have a method that draws the line, based on user input (on click of a draw line button). Currently, each time I draw the line, it draws one more line without replacing (or shifting the old line). However, I want to change it that the current line either shifts to the newly input slope/y-intercept (basically animate it) or to change it so that the current line is deleted and a new line is created instead. This is the current code:

## Slope Equation:

y = mx + b 
      
      
        
        
           m1: 
           b1:

```
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input id="btnGraph" type="button" value="Draw line" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  
  <br />
  <h3>Graph</h3>
  
  <canvas id="Graph" style="background:aliceblue;border:1px solid #AFAFAF" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
 
</fieldset>

  <script>
  function Graph(config) {
    // user defined properties
    this.canvas = document.getElementById(config.canvasId);
    this.minX = config.minX;
    this.minY = config.minY;
    this.maxX = config.maxX;
    this.maxY = config.maxY;
    this.unitsPerTick = config.unitsPerTick;

    // constants
    this.axisColor = '#aaa';
    this.font = '8pt Calibri';
    this.tickSize = 20;

    // relationships
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
    this.rangeX = this.maxX - this.minX;
    this.rangeY = this.maxY - this.minY;
    this.unitX = this.canvas.width / this.rangeX;
    this.unitY = this.canvas.height / this.rangeY;
    this.centerY = Math.round(Math.abs(this.minY / this.rangeY) * this.canvas.height);
    this.centerX = Math.round(Math.abs(this.maxX / this.rangeX) * this.canvas.width);
    this.iteration = (this.maxX - this.minX) / 1000;
    this.scaleX = this.canvas.width / this.rangeX;
    this.scaleY = this.canvas.height / this.rangeY;

    // draw x and y axis
    this.drawXAxis();
    this.drawYAxis();
  }

  Graph.prototype.drawXAxis = function() {
    var context = this.context;
    context.save();
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(0, this.centerY);
    context.lineTo(this.canvas.width, this.centerY);
    context.strokeStyle = this.axisColor;
    context.lineWidth = 2;
    context.stroke();

    // draw tick marks
    var xPosIncrement = this.unitsPerTick * this.unitX;
    var xPos, unit;
    context.font = this.font;
    context.textAlign = 'center';
    context.textBaseline = 'top';

    // draw left tick marks
    xPos = this.centerX - xPosIncrement;
    unit = -1 * this.unitsPerTick;
    while(xPos > 0) {
      context.moveTo(xPos, this.centerY - this.tickSize / 2);
      context.lineTo(xPos, this.centerY + this.tickSize / 2);
      context.stroke();
      context.fillText(unit, xPos, this.centerY + this.tickSize / 2 + 3);
      unit -= this.unitsPerTick;
      xPos = Math.round(xPos - xPosIncrement);
    }

    // draw right tick marks
    xPos = this.centerX + xPosIncrement;
    unit = this.unitsPerTick;
    while(xPos < this.canvas.width) {
      context.moveTo(xPos, this.centerY - this.tickSize / 2);
      context.lineTo(xPos, this.centerY + this.tickSize / 2);
      context.stroke();
      context.fillText(unit, xPos, this.centerY + this.tickSize / 2 + 3);
      unit += this.unitsPerTick;
      xPos = Math.round(xPos + xPosIncrement);
    }
    context.restore();
  };

  Graph.prototype.drawYAxis = function() {
    var context = this.context;
    context.save();
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(this.centerX, 0);
    context.lineTo(this.centerX, this.canvas.height);
    context.strokeStyle = this.axisColor;
    context.lineWidth = 2;
    context.stroke();

    // draw tick marks
    var yPosIncrement = this.unitsPerTick * this.unitY;
    var yPos, unit;
    context.font = this.font;
    context.textAlign = 'right';
    context.textBaseline = 'middle';

    // draw top tick marks
    yPos = this.centerY - yPosIncrement;
    unit = this.unitsPerTick;
    while(yPos > 0) {
      context.moveTo(this.centerX - this.tickSize / 2, yPos);
      context.lineTo(this.centerX + this.tickSize / 2, yPos);
      context.stroke();
      context.fillText(unit, this.centerX - this.tickSize / 2 - 3, yPos);
      unit += this.unitsPerTick;
      yPos = Math.round(yPos - yPosIncrement);
    }

    // draw bottom tick marks
    yPos = this.centerY + yPosIncrement;
    unit = -1 * this.unitsPerTick;
    while(yPos < this.canvas.height) {
      context.moveTo(this.centerX - this.tickSize / 2, yPos);
      context.lineTo(this.centerX + this.tickSize / 2, yPos);
      context.stroke();
      context.fillText(unit, this.centerX - this.tickSize / 2 - 3, yPos);
      unit -= this.unitsPerTick;
      yPos = Math.round(yPos + yPosIncrement);
    }
    context.restore();
  };


   Graph.prototype.drawLine = function(slope, yintercept, color, thickness) {

    var context = this.context;

    // draw x and y axis
    this.drawXAxis();
    this.drawYAxis();

    //context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);

    context.save();
    context.save();
    this.transformContext();
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(this.minX, slope * this.minX + yintercept);

    for(var x = this.minX + this.iteration; x <= this.maxX; x += this.iteration) {
      context.lineTo(x, slope * x + yintercept);
    }

    context.restore();
    context.lineJoin = 'round';
    context.lineWidth = thickness;
    context.strokeStyle = color;
    context.stroke();
    context.restore();
  };

  Graph.prototype.transformContext = function() {
    var context = this.context;

    // move context to center of canvas
    this.context.translate(this.centerX, this.centerY);

    /*
     * stretch grid to fit the canvas window, and
     * invert the y scale so that that increments
     * as you move upwards
     */
    context.scale(this.scaleX, -this.scaleY);
  };

var line = {
    m: m1,
    b: b1,
}

function animate() {
    if (frameCount < 160) {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }
    line.m = m1;
    line.b = b1;
    drawLine(line.m, line.b, 'blue', 3);
    frameCount++;
}

</script>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
           
    var myGraph = new Graph({
     canvasId: 'Graph',
     minX: -10,
     minY: -10,
     maxX: 10,
     maxY: 10,
     unitsPerTick: 1
    });      
    
    myGraph.drawLine(1, 0, 'blue', 3);
    
 
  $("#btnGraph").click(function(){
  
  //myGraph.clearCanvas()
  

    var m1,b1,m2,b2 = 0;

    m1 = parseFloat($("#m1").val());
    b1 = parseFloat($("#b1").val());

   
    var myGraph = new Graph({
     canvasId: 'Graph',
     minX: -10,
     minY: -10,
     maxX: 10,
     maxY: 10,
     unitsPerTick: 1
    });      
    
    myGraph.drawLine(m1, b1, 'blue', 3);
    
  });
 
 });
 
 </script>
```

I am not sure if the issue is with jQuery or with how I draw the line. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

[I added a picture to show what it looks like when adding another line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eL9B.png)

[This picture shows the part of the code that was cut off if it helps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GccBL.png)

Comment: Think of a `canvas` element as (well) a canvas - ie a physical sheet of paper.  If you use a pencil to draw a line, that line won't move.  If you want it to move you have to rub it out and draw it again; or rub out the entire drawing and draw the whole lot again (which is much quicker for a computer to do than it would be on a piece of paper, of course, so not as bad as it sounds).  Start here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Basic_animations

Comment: The weird part is that if I add a clearRec statement, any lines I try drawing after do not show up. Basically instead of erasing any previous lines, it prevents future lines from being drawn and I am not sure why

Answer (score 1):

As it was explained to you in the comment, you must erase and redraw (This is really optimal, that's how canvas works)

So add the following line of code before drawing the axes

```
// draw x and y axis
      this.context.clearRect(0,0,this.canvas.width,this.canvas.height)
      this.drawXAxis();
      this.drawYAxis();
```

You can check it out in this fork I made to your [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/danielm2402/pn2eLq5a/3/)

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I really appreciate it and thanks for explaining how it works as well!